# How to update time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = formatAMPM();

function formatAMPM() {
   var d = new Date(),
   minutes = d.getMinutes().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes(),
   hours = d.getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + d.getHours() : d.getHours(),
   ampm = d.getHours() >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am',
   months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
   days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
   return days[d.getDay()] + ' - ' + months[d.getMonth()] + '. ' + d.getDate() + '. ' + d.getFullYear() + ' - ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ampm;
}
```

Can someone help so that it updates every minute?

Comment: Use, `setInterval(function, delay)`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: inside the function formatAMPM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code with `setInterval`:

```js
setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = formatAMPM();
}, 1000);

    function formatAMPM() {
        var d = new Date(),
            seconds = d.getSeconds().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + d.getSeconds() : d.getSeconds(),
            minutes = d.getMinutes().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes(),
            hours = d.getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + d.getHours() : d.getHours(),
            ampm = d.getHours() >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am',
            months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
        return days[d.getDay()] + ' - ' + months[d.getMonth()] + '. ' + d.getDate() + '. ' + d.getFullYear() + ' - ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ampm;
      }
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function called `setInterval()` is used to regularly run some code.

The first argument is function name and the second is interval in milliseconds.

For example, replace this:

```
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = formatAMPM();
```

With this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = formatAMPM();
}, 60 * 1000);
```

Where 60 * 1000 is one minute in ms.

Comment: If that helped, you can click the checkmark button on my post to accept it as answer. Thanks! @Sam

Answer (score 0):

Like following:

```
setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = formatAMPM();
}, 60000); // 60000 miliseconds
```